# Stack line numbers/file locations in vi

Tags: vim, vi

A lot of the time I'm reading through code and going from function to function, simulating a call stack. Once I get to the bottom, I need to work my way backwards to see how the returned values are handled, but often times I've forgotten what function (10 or so calls up) was called or where it was in the file.

I recently discovered I can walk through the find history with `/^` (forward slash up-arrow). This works, but doesn't always get me exactly what I need.

Is there a way to "bookmark", in order, a list of locations so that I can walk through them in either direction? For example:

- Line 100 - `read_desc` calls `desc_read_dev`
- Line 1200 - `desc_read_dev` calls `dev_read`
- Line 200 - `dev_read` calls `out`
- Line 10 - `out` returns `EOK`

I'd then like to walk that EOK back up to `dev_read` and see what happens there, then walk that back to `desc_read_dev` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the [`:help jumplist`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#jumplist)?

Every search (with `/`, and `n`/`N`) and also other motions (that cover more than a short distance, so `j`, `w`, etc are out) adds an entry there, and you can go back with `<C-O>`, and forward again with `<C-I>` (which is the same as `<Tab>`).

You can also explicitly set a jump point via `m'`.

#### And tags

As your use case is navigation through a call stack, I'd also like to highlight the related *tag stack*. You need to generate a database of function definitions first (`ctags` supports many programming languages), and then there are commands for tag lookup, jumps, and going back in the stack. (All of that is recorded as regular jumps as well.) See [`:help tags`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tags) for details.

#### Advanced stage

You probably don't need this as a beginner, but plugins like my [EnhancedJumps plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2695) extend the built-in jumplist with jumps that stay inside the current buffer, or the opposite, directly jump to the next location in another buffer.